# Vuejs - show autocomplete suggestions while user digit

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, autocomplete

I have this [js fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/xrq5ng68/3/). I want to create a suggestions autocomplete using vuejs. At the moment I've achived only in part the scope, I have a problem with the suggestions. They will be placed under the user input chars and it's not exactly what I was expecting, I want to do something similar to the autocompleto of a smartphone keyboard where the suggested words will be displayed while the user digit a word. Can anyone help me?

```html
<div id="app">
  <textarea id="input" v-model="input" @input="predictWord()"></textarea>
  <span id="suggestion" ref="suggestion"></span>
</div>
```

```
#app {
  .input {
    position: relative;
  }
  #suggestion {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Vue prototype code

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
        input: null,
      t9: null,
      words: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
        this.init();
  },
    methods: {
    init() {
        axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/napolux/paroleitaliane/master/paroleitaliane/660000_parole_italiane.txt'
      }).then( (res) => {
            this.words = res.data.split('\n'); 
            this.t9 = Predictionary.instance();
            this.t9.addWords(this.words);
      });   
    },
    predictWord() {
        let suggestion;
        this.countChars();
      suggestion = this.t9.predict(this.input);
      this.$refs.suggestion.innerText = suggestion[0];
    },
        countChars() {
        console.log(this.input.length);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a working snippet: simplified it a bit, added a loading state (as the dictionary is quite large), updated the resulting output, so it's not dependent on any DOM element.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
      input: null,
      t9: null,
      suggestion: [],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.init();
  },
  methods: {
    async init() {
      this.loading = true
      try {
        const {
          data = ''
        } = await axios({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/napolux/paroleitaliane/master/paroleitaliane/660000_parole_italiane.txt'
        })
        this.t9 = Predictionary.instance();
        const a = data.split('\n').filter(e => e)
        this.t9.addWords(a)
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
      } finally {
        this.loading = false
      }
    },
    predictWord: _.debounce(function() {
      this.suggestion = this.input ? this.t9.predict(this.input) : [];
    }, 300),
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@0.21.1/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/predictionary/dist/predictionary.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <textarea id="input" v-model="input" @input="predictWord" :disabled="loading"></textarea><br />
  <span id="suggestion">{{ suggestion.join(', ') }}</span>
</div>
```

Also added a `debounce` function, so the prediction doesn't have to run so many times - 300ms is a reasonable delay in my experience.

Comment: very nice, thank you. Is also possible to obtain somethink like the one illustrated in [this article](https://webdevtrick.com/javascript-typing-suggestions/)?

Comment: @newbiedev yes, of course - but that is something different. That is called `autocomplete` or `typeahead`. But that whole thing is dependant on the formatting & usage of input fields - those are explained [here](https://webdevtrick.com/javascript-typing-suggestions/) in detail